# A JavaScript error occurred when running Electron app: Error: spawn adb ENOENT

Tags: android, node.js, npm, electron, subprocess

#### Overview

I am fairly new in using electron apps, that being said I am building an application using nodeJS as the backend.

#### Details

Im calling the ***adb logcat*** command to scrape specific processes and compare to a web resource. When testing locally the application runs as expected, meaning there is no issue with spawnign an adb command.

Here is a snippet how I spawn a subprocesses:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');    
const subprocess = spawn('adb', ['logcat', '-s', 'foo'], {
      detached: true 
    });
.
.
.
data = []
            subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
                let temp = data.toString();
                dataArr.push(temp)
            });

            subprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
                setTimeout(fooTemp,15, 'close');
                
            });
```

When building and deploying the app I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: spawn adb ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

#### Question

Obviously I'm missing something, is there a way to run adb commands on a production app? Seems like its not able to spawn a child process. Any leads would be appreciated!

Comment: Try using the full path, i.e `/path/to/adb`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano how would that work when setting the build live? Other users might have a different directory.

Comment: or even not have `adb` at all...

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I need to have `adb` as part of the program as its one of the main components. I just find it strange that it works in the dev build but not when building the package

Comment: May help: https://www.matthewslipper.com/2019/09/22/everything-you-wanted-electron-child-process.html